# How to create this dynamic PIVOT view where the price of 3 fruits are not changing simultaneously?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot, transpose

[The Initial Data View, we have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQyWV.jpg)
Lets consider this table as Table A.
Here we can see that there are 3 markets: A,B,C and there are 3 fruits: Apple, Banana, Strawberry.
There is Start Date and End Date for each of the fruits of each market. These dates imply that the price of the fruit is applicable b/w that interval of dates. If the End Date is empty that means the rate is still applicable.

Now from this table, we want a transposed view of the table. And the final output we want is:
[The View, we want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMASq.jpg)
Lets consider this table as Table B.

This looks like a simple PIVOT function in SQL to transpose the rates and we tried that. But the result we are getting is not expected. The output is coming out to be:
[The Output, we are getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uEqe.jpg)
Lets consider this table as Table C.

The problem is that as in markets A and B, the rates of the 3 fruits are not simultaneously changing, the PIVOT function is not giving expected results.

We have tried the simple pivot function on the Table A:

The code we are using for the PIVOT-

PIVOT(MAX(PRICE/kg)) FOR FRUIT IN
('Apple_Price', 'Banana_Price', 'Strawberry_Price')
AS (MARKET, START_DATE, END_DATE, Apple_Price, Banana_Price, Strawberry_Price)

We have also tried another method where we tried to join 3 times separately Table A. But it is also not working.

Comment: please include all information in text form in your post, not in images

Comment: this does not appear to be mysql; please tag with the database you *are* using instead